# How can I open "Konsole" from a shortcut key?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, konsole

I have Linux Mint 18 Sarah KDE 64-bit and I'm trying to set up a shortcut key to open "Konsole", but I cannot find it on "shortcut options".

Thanks you!

Comment: Are you sure that you are using [tag:linux-mint]? cause, Mint doesn't have [tag:konsole] it has [tag:Terminal]

Comment: @user449077 starting with mint 19 it dropped support for kde this is for 18, that has support for kde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in a console :

```
   systemsettings || systemsettings5
```

- search the *shortcuts* part

[image]

- *custom shortcuts*
- click *edit*, new *global shortcut*, *command/url*
- choose your trigger with the beyboard keys and the action : `konsole`

Comment: Sorry but It doesn't appear

Comment: So fill a bug report on kde bugs